# Copy .txt file to CMD

Tags: batch-file

How do I copy a text in .txt file and paste it on A program.

How do I paste this
[image: How do I paste this]

To this
[image: To this]

to be like this?
[image: to be like this?]

Appreciate your help. using batch file

somehow like this question:
[start program with a .bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBT9A.png)

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **Unfortunately, we can’t run your screenshot as code.**

Comment: Your question asks about pasting into the command prompt window, `cmd.exe`; that however means that your question should be tagged [cmd] not [batch-file]. If you want a batch file, what happens if you rename `PATH.txt` to `PATH.txt.cmd` then double click it?

Comment: I just want to paste this text to cmd C:\IEST Casino\SG8\casino.exe
C:\IEST Casino\RTG\casino.exe
C:\IEST Casino\AS\Alfastreet.exe
C:\IEST Casino\PNG\Instawin - Play N Go.lnk
C:\IEST Casino\PT\casino.exe
C:\IEST Casino\PP\Instawin - Pragmatic Play.exe
 using .bat

Comment: pasting into the command prompt window, using a .txt file, for example my PATH.txt is contains C:\IEST Casino\SG8\casino.exe
C:\IEST Casino\RTG\casino.exe
C:\IEST Casino\AS\Alfastreet.exe
C:\IEST Casino\PNG\Instawin - Play N Go.lnk
C:\IEST Casino\PT\casino.exe
C:\IEST Casino\PP\Instawin - Pragmatic Play.exe
how can i get that text from a notepad and paste it in a cmd

Comment: Perhaps `@Title C:\GameLobby\Win10URLProtocol.exe&Type PATH.txt` will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use file input method like so:

```
Win10URLProtocol.exe<PATH.txt
```

Where:

- `Win10URLProtocol.exe` mean the exe file that you want to send all the texts from a file
- `<` mean use file as input stream
- `PATH.txt` mean input from file PATH.txt

There is no way to paste the text into a command prompt windows above. However, you can use method above to send all text into a .exe file instead of paste it.

Comment: may or may not work (depends on how the EXE is programmed to get the Input. (Btw: `no way` should read `no way with pure Batch`. One can use other languages which support some sort of `Sendkey` to do it.)